# Javascript: How to get a list of an object's prototype chain constructor names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototype

I recently encountered an interesting problem. I am developing with some existing code where, for better or worse, there are often several levels of prototypical inheritance ending in constructors for all kinds of various objects. Each of these ultimately inherit from a *single* base 'class'.

Each constructor follows the following inheritance pattern, where `Sub` is a subclass and `Super` is it's immediate prototype:

```
function Sub(/*args*/) {
    Super.call(this,/*args*/);
}

Sub.prototype = Object.create(Super.prototype);
```

This pattern continues all the way up to the single base class.

Discovering that it would be incredibly beneficial for our needs to store a list of constructor names for each object up the prototype chain, I came up with the following code addition for the base class, which uses the `callee` and `caller` properties of the [**arguments**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object:

```
var curConstructor = arguments.callee;
this.constructorList = [curConstructor.name];

while(curConstructor.caller && curConstructor.caller.name !== ''){
    curConstructor = curConstructor.caller;
    this.constructorList.push(curConstructor.name);
}
```

The main issue with this, is it *only* works if the object was constructed inside of an anonymous function (or global scope). For instance, assuming I have a constructor `SubA1`with prototype `SubA`with prototype `Base`, if I do this:

```
function() {
  var aOk = new SubA1();
  function oops() {
    var aNotOk = new SubA1();
  }
  oops();
}
```

`aOk`'s constructor list is: `[Base,SubA,SubA1]`, which is what I want.

`aNotOk`'s constructor list ends up as: `[Base,SubA,SubA1,oops]`.

[**Here's a plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/L74YDUt9jds7fn5PmkeS).

I could fix it by having each constructor add their name to the constructor list themselves, but there are several problems with that, not least of which is the tremendous pain (and debugging / maintenance nightmare) it would be to add code to each of the many many constructor functions.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Note that although the above question was asked in a more general sense, and not specific to Node.js, I am actually working with code in a Node.js environment. Therefore, solutions specific to Node are welcome.

### Update:

In my particular case, all of the constructors are within a namespace. So I can actually solve the problem by performing a check to make sure that the function name exists in the namespace before adding it to the `constructorList`.

Basically, I can do this:

```
var curConstructor = arguments.callee;
this.constructorList = [curConstructor.name];

while(curConstructor.caller){
    curConstructor = curConstructor.caller;

    // Exit if the function name isn't part of the namespace
    if(typeof namespace[curConstructor.name] !== 'function') break;

    this.constructorList.push(curConstructor.name);
}
```

This won't solve it in a generic sense though of course, and it isn't perfect. If the function which calls `new SubA1` for example just happens to have the same name as one of the constructors in the namespace, it will throw the list off. In my particular case, since the constructors follow a unique naming pattern, that occurrence is extremely unlikely.

I am aware that `arguments.callee` is deprecated, and that `Object.constructor` is not trustworthy (it doesn't get me what I want anyway), but I am unaware of any other way to get names of each constructor in the chain by modifying the base 'class' only.

Comment: What is the end problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem... You'd do `Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub` and this will keep track of the constructor functions, the names are usually irrelevant.

Comment: @jfriend00 I want a list of constructor names so they can be invoked later to construct new objects on the fly, as well as help in keeping track of the prototype chain for any particular object.

Comment: Don't you just need the leaf constructor to remake an object of that type?

Comment: If I may, `callee` is deprecated, and you should not rely on `constructor` since it is not a read-only property.

Comment: You may find this post helpful: http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/ if you're trying to walk the prototype chain.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I would just need the leaf constructor *for that type*, but I may want to use a constructor which is somewhere *up* in the middle of the prototype chain, so not necessarily an end leaf. As to your comment about `Object.getPrototypeOf`, I can't use that to get the constructor name, which is what I want.

Comment: @NanoWizard: If you care about names (strings), store them on the prototype. There is no other reliable way.

Comment: @Bergi The name would have to be stored on each prototype individually... as mentioned, modifying each constructor (or its prototype) is also problematic.

Comment: Well, if you have all your classes in a namespace so that your names are available as property names anyway, you can do that programmatically. Not problematically.

Answer (score 2):

This function gets all constructors of a prototype chain, when they are registered as a property of the prototype:

```
function getConstructorChain(obj, type) {
    var cs = [], pt = obj;
    do {
       if (pt = Object.getPrototypeOf(pt)) cs.push(pt.constructor || null);
    } while (pt != null);
    return type == 'names' ? cs.map(function(c) {
        return c ? c.toString().split(/\s|\(/)[1] : null;
    }) : cs;
}
```

Without argument `type`an array of functions is returned, with `type = 'names'` an array of  function-name strings.

Working [FIDDLE with a HTMLDivElement object as example here](http://jsfiddle.net/p50hhugu/6/). Use console.

Comment: This works brilliantly for built-ins and ES 2015 classes (tested in chrome 46), but fails on common inheritance patterns with constructor functions. Was very helpful to me, even if it doesn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that it works fine with coffeescript/babel 'classes'. But `function Foo(){} function Bar(){} Bar.prototype = new Foo;` and the like fail.